# Cómo hacer que un intent pida un parámetro al usuario? swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy tratando de armar el código para un intent, en el cual se le pida al usuario el número de la página de un libro que quiera leer para redireccionarlo rápidamente. Lógicamente no se debería hacer un intent por cada página que haya en el libro, así que debe haber una solución más fácil/lógica.

Dejo el código básico de intent:

```
struct SiriNumeroPagina: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Página"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Busca el número de la página")
    
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Busca el número de la página")
    }
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        
        return .result()
    }
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar con esto, se lo agradecería mucho.